# What do you call the source of a "said" quote?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

The source of a quote that was written (perhaps in a book) would be the "author" of the quote. What if the quote was *said*? Is it the "dictator" of the quote? That sounds odd and "speaker" just doesn't sit right with me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: *Author* still works, IMO

Comment: And so does _source_.

Comment: If I'm asking for people to provide a "source" for a quote, they may be inclined to find a website that shows the quote. Instead, I just want the name of the person that said the quote.

Comment: What's wrong with *speaker*?

Comment: "Please provide the speaker of your quote." To my ears, just doesn't seem like the best word that can be used. I suppose it's technically fine, but I'd like to know if there is an alternative.

Comment: *Originator* (of the quote)

Comment: Please provide the *orator* of your quote?

Comment: Out of originator, orator, and speaker: speaker still sounds the best, unfortunately. I suppose there may be no better option.

Comment: Also, you should probably not call it "your quote" unless you are instructing the speaker. Consider "the quote" or "Please cite the quote's speaker."

Comment: The word is *author*. And Armen said so in the very first comment. Why is everyone after him falling over themselves trying to reinvent the bicycle? It is *author*. "Please provide the author of the quote."  Not *sayer*, not *orator*, not *speaker*. It is *author*.  And nobody at all will take that to mean "please provide a URL". So simple. Come on.

Comment: By 'said' do you mean 'spoken' (as opposed to written)? Also, what is the context? Are you a journalist that a senate sub-committee is questioning? Are you writing a paper for a class? Or are you asking in a Q&A site?

Comment: @Mitch Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Quotee* ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quotee), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotee)) just means the person who is quoted.  It applies regardless of how the quotee used the words (spoken, written).

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it:

**author** *n*
Far more commonly, and narrowly, defined as

> **1** A writer of a book, article, or document ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/author))

Nearly all definitions in most of the major dictionaries include "writing" as an essential part of the definition. Secondary meanings given are generally in the nature of metaphorical or overly-literary/ formal use that is an overly broad

> **1.3** An originator of a plan or idea (*ibid*)

that is not necessarily even about a literary piece, let alone a quotable one.

Wikipedia, on the other hand, places the broader definition first:

> An author is broadly defined as "the person who originated or gave existence to anything" and whose authorship determines responsibility for what was created. Narrowly defined, an author is the originator of any written work and can also be described as a writer.

But again, it is not necessarily about a literary work in any way.

In summary, the word *author* **cannot** mean "the originator of an utterance," although it does not exclude such an instance.

We may thus have to look at alternatives such as *source* and *speaker* as a compromise. (Both seem inadequate to me, but *source* is widely used.)

Finally, a last resort could probably be:
**utterer**

> *New sets of words, new collocations of old phrases are new, whatever the expressed intention of the utterer.* ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/utter#utter-2))

Comment: Technically, utterer is correct (just like originator, orator, and speaker), but in terms of cacophony? Yuck.

Comment: Reg Dwight gives the accepted (by most anglophones) view here: 'The word is **author**. And Armen said so in the very first comment. Why is everyone after him falling over themselves trying to reinvent the bicycle? It is **author**.'

Answer (score -1):

As @Armen wrote, *author* is appropriate since it does not necessarily refer to writing — although not all dictionaries list this (Oxford doesn't, Cambridge has 'a person who begins or creates something'). Indeed, the etymology is (according to etymonline.com) :

> author (n.)  c.1300, autor "father," from Old French auctor, acteor
>   "author, originator, creator, instigator (12c., Modern French auteur),
>   from Latin auctorem (nominative auctor) "enlarger, founder, master,
>   leader," literally "one who causes to grow," agent noun from auctus,
>   past participle of augere "to increase" (see augment). Meaning "one
>   who sets forth written statements" is from late 14c. The -t- changed
>   to -th- 16c. on mistaken assumption of Greek origin.

Comment: Please see definitions, not etymology, first.

Comment: @Kris [ngrams](http://goo.gl/DdSilI) shows significant usage for "author of the quote". Please remember that dictionaries don't make language.

Comment: Oxford **certainly** 'lists this'. Unless you mean a dictionary other than the one many people will think you mean. In which case you should certainly make it clear that you're _not_ talking about the Oxford English Dictionary here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No exceptions. Please see my answer on this page.

Comment: @Kris The _Oxford Dictionary of Plant-Lore_ seems to miss it :-0. Seriously, thanks for the corrective. But I don't understand 'In summary, the word _author_ cannot mean "the originator of an utterance," although it does not exclude such an instance'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Consider: You cannot say *a man* and mean "a (male) student" although the definition of *man* includes a male student -- overly broad.

Comment: @Kris Of course you can. It's one of the defined senses. I can say 'Can you see the man with those large binoculars?', though it is ambiguous. There's no law saying 'English forbids the use of ambiguous expressions'. Of course, it's best to disambiguate in some way. But you mustn't say 'You can't say ...'. You'd be barring a large proportion of idiomatic English. Which some might say would be wicked.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course, go ahead. Good Luck.